# How can I display text when hovering over a legend item in Python Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

Sorry for asking a question with very little info,  but its a very simple question.
I have looked thru the documentation of Plotly (python) and can't find a way to simply add hover text when hovering over an item in the legend.
The names of the traces are very long,  so I am just using the defaults , ie trace 0. I would like to show the real name of the trace when I hover over the entry in the legend.  Is this possible with the Python Plotly library?

Here is an example.  I would like to be able to hover over "trace 0" in the legend and see a popup showing "the y value is the square of x", but still see "trace 0" in the legend.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace_0_name = "the y value is the square of x"
trace_1_name = "the y value is the cube of x"
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2**2,3**2]))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2**3,3**3]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean if it's possible with `plotly`? I'd try something like `hovertemplate`, but a more accurate answer depends on how you build your figure. Could you post some dummy code, please?

Comment: @Vitalizzare I do need to generate the plot from Python, ie switching to pure javascript is not an option if that is what you were asking.

Comment: Why bother hovering if you can name the graph, why do you need to? Try this: `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2**2,3**2], name=trace_0_name))`

Comment: @r-beginners The problem with that approach is that the value of trace_0_name is what shows up in the legend, and trace_0_name can be a really long string (100+ characters - its the hierarchical name of a transistor terminal on a very large chip).
I am already using the very long name in the `text` field of the trace when I add it, which is helpful,  but I would really like to be able to just hover over each entry in the legend and see the very long name.  
If I can't get this to work,  I might just use the long name but put the legend below the plot.

Comment: In conclusion, the ability to hover over a legend is not provided at this time. Therefore, if the legend name is long, it can be shortened by using textwrap or by narrowing the graph drawing area. Please refer to the [examples](https://community.plotly.com/t/avoid-legend-automatically-repositioning/12979/4) in the community.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the info!  For now I will go with using the long name, but placing the legend above the plot.  I will post my code shortly in case anyone else has a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Based on @r-beginners comment above it does not seem that at this time we can hover over legend entries in Python.

My current workaround is to use the long name, but place the legend above the plot.  Here is an example using my workaround.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace_0_name = "the y value is the square of x"
trace_1_name = "the y value is the cube of x"
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2**2,3**2], name=trace_0_name))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2**3,3**3], name=trace_1_name))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor='bottom', y=1.0, x=0))
fig.show()
```

and the resulting plot:
[image]